# LOESS FUNCTION SIMULATIONS IN R

Tags: r, simulation, loess

Using loess(y~x) and predict, i have found loess estimate of a random variable in R. Now, i want to perform 100 Monte Carlo Simulations to find the standard error. I have used the following R code but it is returning the same value in all 100 simulations. Please tell me where i went wrong.

```
set.seed(6)
pn = replicate(100,predict(fit,data=data.frame(X=78)),simplify=FALSE)
plot(pn)
sd(pn)
```

Comment: if you always provide the same X (i.e X=78), and fit, you will get back the same value. What exactly are you trying to do

Comment: If you are predicting the model in the same point `data.frame(X=78)` the result will be the same.

Comment: The loess estimate is a random variable. I am trying to find the standard error of the loess estimate by performing 1000 monte carlo simulations.

Comment: I suspect you want to find the the standard error of prediction? The usual approach would be bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

As has been explained in the comments: If you give predict the same `fit` object and the same `X` value, it will always return the same answer. There are two obvious ways to approach this.

*First:* The `predict` function you are using is really `predict.loess` from the `stats` package. It has an argument `se` and if you call `predict(fit, ..., se = TRUE)` it will return an estimated standard error for each predicted value. So check, if that does what you want without you programming it for yourself:
cf. http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/predict.loess

*Second:* If you want different predictions from your `predict` call you will need to pass it different `fit` objects. You could get these from bootstrapping the data you feed to `loess` als Roland suggested in the comments.

Comment: Thank you all. Thank you so much @Bernhard